# How do i export a variable/property in go lang

Tags: go, package, webserver

I am trying to create an MVC web app in golang without using any framework. How I plan to achieve it is to create an instance of a http.Server {} with a http.NewServeMux() as it's handler as coded below:

```
 sm := http.NewServeMux()
    sm.Handle("/route1", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/front-office/index.html")
    }))
    sm.Handle("/route2", handleSomething())
    sm.Handle("/route3", handleSomething())
    sm.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))


    frontEndUIServer := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":9000",
        Handler:  sm,
    }
    go frontEndUIServer.ListenAndServe()
```

then make property `sm` exportable so that any other go files can import it and create handlers on it, thereby implementing my controller. Since I am new to goLang, my question now is how do I make property `sm` exportable?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/basics/3

Answer (score 1):

When you ask "how do I make property sm exportable" I assume you mean in the node sense? If so, the concept you're looking for is "packages".

https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/11

This allows making reference to functionality in one package in other packages using "import". Note that the name of the function you want to access must start with a capital letter vs lowercase which can only be referenced with the package.

Typically the web server is created in the "main" function / package with controllers attached to the routes you define.

This is a good basic example: https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/03.2.html

Answer (score 0):

You could define your web app in a `mywebapp` package like this:

```golang
package mywebapp

import "net/http"

var SM *http.ServeMux

func init() {
    SM = http.NewServeMux()
    SM.Handle("/route1", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/front-office/index.html")
    }))
    SM.Handle("/route2", handleSomething())
    SM.Handle("/route3", handleSomething())
    SM.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))

    frontEndUIServer := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":9000",
        Handler: SM,
    }
    go frontEndUIServer.ListenAndServe()
}
```

The `ServeMux` used by the server is exported so other packages can add handlers. The server starts as soon as the package is imported.